# xCode only shows iOS 8 folder in frameworks windows?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

Why does the framework window in xcode only show the iOS8 folder?
What if I want to support iOS 7?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of those frameworks will work with iOS 7 despite them being listed under a folder named iOS 8.1, they are simply the most up-to-date versions of those frameworks.

See the following link for a list of frameworks and the OS in which they were first available:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html

Notice that frameworks like "CloudKit" were introduced in iOS 8 and will cause problems when you try to build for your deployment target of iOS 7.